# ¿Cómo enviar una variable local desde una vista hasta otro controlador?

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo este javascript que me captura una variable (`scom`):

```
<script>

   $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
       run();
   });

   function run() {
       var scom = $('[id*=DropDownListReports] option:selected').text();
       alert('Selected Value is : ' + scom);
    // Selected Text
     // var scom = $('[id*=DropDownListReports] option:selected').text();

   //return scom;
   };

</script>
```

Este script está en la vista `index`. Quiero pasar esa variable a un controlador o mejor dicho a un PRIVATE VOID que se encuentra en un controlador distinto al de mi index. Quiero esto para que me genere una lista, la cual estará filtrada con el dato que necesito.

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos formas de poder resolver el problema que planteas, depende del objetivo del envío de datos (para ambos casos, la petición debe llegar a un Controller, no se puede que llegue directamente a un método)

1. Hacer una redirección y enviar el parámetro por medio de la URL
2. Ejecutar una llamada Ajax enviando los datos que consideres necesario.

## Enviar datos por medio la URL

Justo despúes de que obtienes el dato `scom`, se envía la redirección a la página que desees, poniendo como parámetro `?scom=123`, suponiendo que el valor obtenido en esa variable es `123`.

```
function run() {
   var scom = $('[id*=DropDownListReports] option:selected').text();
    window.location.href = "{site}/{Controller}/{Action}?scom=" + scom;
};
```

## Enviar datos por medio de una llamada Ajax

De igual forma, al obtener el valor de `scom` se ejecutará la llamada:

```
function run() {
    var scom = $('[id*=DropDownListReports] option:selected').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/{Controller}/{Action}",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "scom": scom };,
        success: function (result) {
            //Hacer algo con el resultado en caso que la petición haya sido exitosa
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //Hacer algo con el resultado en caso que la petición haya fallado
        }
    });
};
```

Para ambos casos considera lo siguiente:

- **`{site}`**: es el nombre de tu sitio, si haces pruebas locales toma en cuenta `localhost`.
- **`{Controller}`**: es el nombre de tu Controlador de la aplicación.
- **`{Action}`**: es el nombre de la acción a donde llegará la petición.

En tu código C#, la declaración de tu Controller deberá ser de la siguiente forma suponiendo que tu Controller se llama `Test` y tu Action se llama `Index`:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index(string scom)
    {
        AlgunMetodo(scom);
        return View();
    }

    private void AlgunMetodo(string scom)
    {
        //Acciones a realizar con la variable scom
    }
}
```

Como buena práctica, en la clase del Controller no se recomienda tener algún otro método que no sean Action, es preferible manejar alguna otra clase para realizar las operaciones necesarias con las variables u objetos recibidos.